# P10 Led Matrix 64x32 not show true in pixeltime (PxMatrix library) with ESP8266 NodeMCU

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I am learning how to control P10 Led matrix 64x32 with NodeModule MCU ESP8266, I google and found this library https://github.com/2dom/PxMatrix and this tutorial https://www.instructables.com/RGB-LED-Matrix-With-an-ESP8266/. I believed that I wire between P10 and ESP8266 in true way in the tutorial, but that P10 led does not display as the example:
[image]

The true result will be:

[image]

This is my wire diagram:

[image]

[image]

This is my code:

```
// This is how many color levels the display shows - the more the slower the update
//#define PxMATRIX_COLOR_DEPTH 4

// Defines the speed of the SPI bus (reducing this may help if you experience noisy images)
//#define PxMATRIX_SPI_FREQUENCY 20000000

// Creates a second buffer for backround drawing (doubles the required RAM)
//#define PxMATRIX_double_buffer true

#include <PxMatrix.h>

// Pins for LED MATRIX
#ifdef ESP32

#define P_LAT 22
#define P_A 19
#define P_B 23
#define P_C 18
#define P_D 5
#define P_E 15
#define P_OE 16
hw_timer_t * timer = NULL;
portMUX_TYPE timerMux = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;

#endif

#ifdef ESP8266

#include <Ticker.h>
Ticker display_ticker;
#define P_LAT 16
#define P_A 5
#define P_B 4
#define P_C 15
#define P_D 12
#define P_E 0
#define P_OE 2

#endif

#define matrix_width 64
#define matrix_height 32

// This defines the 'on' time of the display is us. The larger this number,
// the brighter the display. If too large the ESP will crash
uint8_t display_draw_time=10; //30-70 is usually fine

//PxMATRIX display(32,16,P_LAT, P_OE,P_A,P_B,P_C);
PxMATRIX display(64,32,P_LAT, P_OE,P_A,P_B,P_C,P_D);
//PxMATRIX display(64,64,P_LAT, P_OE,P_A,P_B,P_C,P_D,P_E);

// Some standard colors
uint16_t myRED = display.color565(255, 0, 0);
uint16_t myGREEN = display.color565(0, 255, 0);
uint16_t myBLUE = display.color565(0, 0, 255);
uint16_t myWHITE = display.color565(255, 255, 255);
uint16_t myYELLOW = display.color565(255, 255, 0);
uint16_t myCYAN = display.color565(0, 255, 255);
uint16_t myMAGENTA = display.color565(255, 0, 255);
uint16_t myBLACK = display.color565(0, 0, 0);

uint16_t myCOLORS[8]={myRED,myGREEN,myBLUE,myWHITE,myYELLOW,myCYAN,myMAGENTA,myBLACK};

uint8_t static weather_icons[]={0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
  ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xdf,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x20,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
  ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00
  ,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00
  ,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00
  ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x20,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xdf,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00
  ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00
  ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
  ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xdf,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x07,0xdf,0x07,0xff,0x07,0xff,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
  ,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0xff,0xe0,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
};

#ifdef ESP8266
// ISR for display refresh
void display_updater()
{
  display.display(display_draw_time);
}
#endif

#ifdef ESP32
void IRAM_ATTR display_updater(){
  // Increment the counter and set the time of ISR
  portENTER_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);
  display.display(display_draw_time);
  portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);
}
#endif


void display_update_enable(bool is_enable)
{

#ifdef ESP8266
  if (is_enable)
    display_ticker.attach(0.004, display_updater);
  else
    display_ticker.detach();
#endif

#ifdef ESP32
  if (is_enable)
  {
    timer = timerBegin(0, 80, true);
    timerAttachInterrupt(timer, &display_updater, true);
    timerAlarmWrite(timer, 4000, true);
    timerAlarmEnable(timer);
  }
  else
  {
    timerDetachInterrupt(timer);
    timerAlarmDisable(timer);
  }
#endif
}



void setup() {

 Serial.begin(9600);
  // Define your display layout here, e.g. 1/8 step, and optional SPI pins begin(row_pattern, CLK, MOSI, MISO, SS)
  display.begin(16);
  //display.begin(8, 14, 13, 12, 4);

  // Define multiplex implemention here {BINARY, STRAIGHT} (default is BINARY)
  //display.setMuxPattern(BINARY);

  // Set the multiplex pattern {LINE, ZIGZAG,ZZAGG, ZAGGIZ, WZAGZIG, VZAG, ZAGZIG} (default is LINE)
  //display.setScanPattern(LINE);

  // Rotate display
  //display.setRotate(true);

  // Flip display
  //display.setFlip(true);

  // Control the minimum color values that result in an active pixel
  //display.setColorOffset(5, 5,5);

  // Set the multiplex implemention {BINARY, STRAIGHT} (default is BINARY)
  //display.setMuxPattern(BINARY);

  // Set the color order {RRGGBB, RRBBGG, GGRRBB, GGBBRR, BBRRGG, BBGGRR} (default is RRGGBB)
  //display.setColorOrder(RRGGBB);

  // Set the time in microseconds that we pause after selecting each mux channel
  // (May help if some rows are missing / the mux chip is too slow)
  //display.setMuxDelay(0,1,0,0,0);

  // Set the number of panels that make up the display area width (default is 1)
  //display.setPanelsWidth(2);

  // Set the brightness of the panels (default is 255)
  //display.setBrightness(50);

  // Set driver chip type
  //display.setDriverChip(FM6124);

  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextColor(myCYAN);
  display.setCursor(2,0);
  display.print("Pixel");
  display.setTextColor(myMAGENTA);
  display.setCursor(2,8);
  display.print("Time");
  display_update_enable(true);

  delay(3000);

}
union single_double{
  uint8_t two[2];
  uint16_t one;
} this_single_double;

// This draws the weather icons
void draw_weather_icon (uint8_t icon)
{
  if (icon>10)
  icon=10;
  for (int yy=0; yy<10;yy++)
  {
    for (int xx=0; xx<10;xx++)
    {
      uint16_t byte_pos=(xx+icon*10)*2+yy*220;
      this_single_double.two[1]=weather_icons[byte_pos];
      this_single_double.two[0]=weather_icons[byte_pos+1];
      display.drawPixel(1+xx,yy,this_single_double.one);
    }
  }
}

unsigned long last_draw=0;
void scroll_text(uint8_t ypos, unsigned long scroll_delay, String text, uint8_t colorR, uint8_t colorG, uint8_t colorB)
{
    uint16_t text_length = text.length();
    display.setTextWrap(false);  // we don't wrap text so it scrolls nicely
    display.setTextSize(1);
    display.setRotation(0);
    display.setTextColor(display.color565(colorR,colorG,colorB));

    // Asuming 5 pixel average character width
    for (int xpos=matrix_width; xpos>-(matrix_width+text_length*5); xpos--)
    {
      display.setTextColor(display.color565(colorR,colorG,colorB));
      display.clearDisplay();
      display.setCursor(xpos,ypos);
      display.println(text);
      delay(scroll_delay);
      yield();

      // This might smooth the transition a bit if we go slow
      // display.setTextColor(display.color565(colorR/4,colorG/4,colorB/4));
      // display.setCursor(xpos-1,ypos);
      // display.println(text);

      delay(scroll_delay/5);
      yield();

    }
}

uint8_t icon_index=0;
void loop() {
  scroll_text(1,50,"Welcome to PxMatrix!",96,96,250);
  display.clearDisplay();

  draw_weather_icon(icon_index);
  icon_index++;
  if (icon_index>10)
    icon_index=0;

  for (int xx=0; xx<16;xx++)
  {
    display.drawLine(xx+16,0,xx+16,5,display.color565(xx*16,0,0));
    display.drawLine(xx+16,6,xx+16,10,display.color565(0,xx*16,0));
    display.drawLine(xx+16,11,xx+16,15,display.color565(0,0,xx*16));
  }
  delay(1000);
  for (uint8_t dimm=255; dimm>0; dimm--)
  {
    display.setBrightness(dimm);
    delay(5);
  }
  for (uint8_t dimm=0; dimm<255; dimm++)
  {
    display.setBrightness(dimm);
    delay(5);
  }

}
```

I appreciate if anyone help me to figure it out, I stucked here 3 days. Thanks!

Comment: Why start with a complex pattern?  Light three adjacent pixels with Red, Green, Blue.  If they come up in the wrong place, then address is wrong.  If they come up the wrong color, then value is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I will try it. The reason why I come with this complex pattern because I am new with arduino and this is the example of PxMatrix, so I just wire to connect the ESP and P10 and run the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding

> display.setPanelsWidth(2);
>
> display.setMuxPattern(SHIFTREG_ABC_BIN_DE);

because my led is combined by 2 matrix 32x16.